# doctrine query builder SELECT DISTINCT throws error

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony4

This should be straight forward. I did find a number of posts in SO and elsewhere on this topic, but it just throws the error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 18 near 'thread FROM App\Entity\Message': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

This is for selecting distinct threads on a message module. The query I attempted is:

```
public function getThreads() {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->select('DISTINCT m.thread')
        ->where('m.thread IS NOT NULL')
        ->orderBy('m.thread', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(10)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

The Message entity:

```
class Message
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Ad", inversedBy="messages")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $ad;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Message")
 */
private $thread;
.....
```

To be fair, I did manage to make it work with DQL but, you know, I can't seem to leave it unresolved with query builder.

Here is the DQL, by the way:

```
    public function getThreads() {
    $query = $this->em->createQuery(
        'SELECT DISTINCT(m.thread) FROM App:Message m 
        WHERE m.thread IS NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY m.thread DESC
        LIMIT 10 ');
    return $query->getResult(); 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the `->distinct()` method of the QueryBuilder as per [Doctrine's QueryBuilder documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/latest/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.html)'s example: `$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder() ->select('u') ->distinct() ->from('User', 'u');`?

Comment: I tried that, like this: `        $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
            ->select('m.thread')
            ->distinct()`, but it throws the same error. Also, in doing that, there's nowhere to tell doctrine which column should be distinct.

Comment: Ooops... I stand corrected. Contrary to what I said on my comment above `select('m.thread)` is telling doctrine which column should be distinct. But no matter, the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these solutions, I think your issue is you didn't specify the 'from' in the solution using query builder. Also you can remove the 'm' from the createQueryBuilder() function, this function doesn't receive any parameter. I hope one of these solutions work for you.

**Solution 1**

```
public function getThreads(){
    return $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('DISTINCT m.thread')
                    ->from('App\Entity\Message', 'm')
                    ->where('m.thread IS NOT NULL')
                    ->orderBy('m.thread', 'DESC')
                    ->setMaxResults(10)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
public function getThreads(){
    return $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('m.thread')->distinct()
                    ->from('App\Entity\Message', 'm')
                    ->where('m.thread IS NOT NULL')
                    ->orderBy('m.thread', 'DESC')
                    ->setMaxResults(10)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
}
```

**Solution 3**

```
public function getThreads(){
    $queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder->select('m.thread')->distinct()
                 ->from('App\Entity\Message', 'm')
                 ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->isNotNull('m.thread'))
                 ->orderBy('m.thread', 'DESC')
                 ->setMaxResults(10);

    $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
    $result = $query->getResult();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: It seems that my Symfony/Doctrine app does not agree with your statement about `createQueryBuilder() function` not requiring any parameter. I had already tried that with the `->from()` clause. It throws error `Too few arguments to function Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder(), 0 passed in .../Repository/MessageRepository.php on line 115 and at least 1 expected`. Line 115, as you can imagine is `return $this->createQueryBuilder()` from your first solution above.

Comment: What version of Doctrine are you using?

Comment: Sorry it's my bad, I forgot to add the $em variable (Entity Manager) object. I'm going to update the answer with this change.

Comment: @BernardA, It was useful to you, after I added the 'em' variable?

Comment: Sorry it took a while. I am afraid the error persists even if I add the `$this->em` to the query. Not sure of what's going on.

Comment: Yes, still the same.